# Tomcat TLS Vulnerability Sweet32 Birthday attack

Tags: security, tomcat, ssl, encryption

I have a tomcat service, which doesn't pas a veracode scan. Birthday attacks against TLS ciphers discovered vulnerabilities in Tomcat HTTPS port (8543).

After reading some documentation I found following inormation:

> Found on Tomcat HTTPS (port 8543)
>
> Legacy block ciphers having block size of 64 bits are vulnerable to a
>   practical collision attack when used in CBC mode.  All versions of
>   SSL/TLS protocol support cipher suites which use DES or 3DES as the
>   symmetric encryption cipher are affected.
>
> Remote attackers can obtain cleartext data via a birthday attack
>   against a long-duration encrypted session.

In a terminal following commands can be executed to test if tomcat is vulnerable for Sweet32 birthday attack.
The following openssl commands can be used to do a manual test:

- openssl s_client -connect localhost:8543 -cipher "DES:3DES" -tls1_2
- openssl s_client -connect localhost:8543 -cipher "DES:3DES" -tls1_1
- openssl s_client -connect localhost:8543 -cipher "DES:3DES" -tls1
- openssl s_client -connect localhost:8543 -cipher "DES:3DES" -ssl3
- openssl s_client -connect localhost:8543 -cipher "DES:3DES" -ssl2

The problem is that I don't have any idea where to block this vulnerability.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Tomcat 8, amend your server.xml file as follows:

```
<Connector port="8543" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" address="192.168.1.1"
enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
keystoreFile="SomeDir/SomeFile.key" keystorePass="extensa"
truststoreFile="SomeDir/SomeFile.truststore" truststorePass="extensa" 
sslProtocol="TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2" 
ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, 
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, ...
"/>
```

Remove ciphers which have 64bits and/or less AND have CBC, CTR, GCM, OCB in their cipher names

Edit the above params to your local installation: keystoreFile, keystorePass, truststoreFile, truststorePass